# jQuery on() click event handler with dynamic data crashing

Tags: event-handling, jquery

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/easLc/

HTML

```
<div class="bar">
  <div class="apple"> apple</div>
  <div class="banana"> banana</div>
  <div class="citrus"> citrus </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
function showAlert(event) {
    inventory = event.data.inventory;
    alert(inventory);        
}

fruits = ["apple", "banana", "citrus"];
inventory = [13, 45, 99];

for (i in fruits) {        
    $(".bar ."+fruits[i]).on("click", {inventory:inventory[i]},showAlert);
}
```

The inventory data I'm passing to the handler is dynamic, not static like the example.  I'm getting the inventory data from asynchronous calls.  After each time the inventory data is updated, I want to pass this data to the handler instead of have the handler get that information again.

What I'm noticing is on some clicks, the handler (I think) is crashing my browser.  Am I creating too many handlers inadvertently? How do I see what handlers were created?  Or what happens during the click event?  I tried adding some console.log to the handler but I don't see them in the console.

Thanks!

Comment: Can we have the real code? With the ajax call and success function please? My guess is that you are adding a .on at every call, but cannot see from what you are showing

Comment: To debug the code in Chrome, press F12 to open developer tools - you'll probably have some errors listed in the console at the bottom.  In Firefox, install Firebug (https://getfirebug.com/) and use that to check the errors.  In IE, press F12 and go to the Console tab to view errors

Comment: @Salketer, my code is really long and still in need of a clean up.  It's probably too confusing to be read at this point.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by .on at every call?  I think that's what I'm doing as well but I'm not sure how to spot it.

Comment: @SteveGreatrex, I was looking at the Chrome's developer tools but I didn't see any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(".bar ."+fruits[i]).off('click',showAlert).on("click", {inventory:inventory[i]},showAlert);
```

This will remove the previously bound event and rebind it... But it is hard to determine if it is the real source of the problem. You can add a console.log('text') in showAlert to see if it is being called more than once.

Comment: I suggest using a namespace for the click event if you are going with this method just in case you have bound other click events and you don't want them unbound.

Comment: @ExplosionPills, I'm not really familiar with namespace and events.  I will dig deeper and learn what that means.  Thanks for the headsup!

Comment: namespaces are easily used. I like to refere them like classes in CSS... If you have an event click, in a namespace you would use 'click.namespace' as eventname, you could even decide to unbind all events from a namespace using '.namespace' as eventname . Explosion Pills is right about using a namespace but if you define a the handler too, off only destroys the event click that triggers the specified handler. http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent multiple bindings by adding some sort of data to the element once it's been bound (a clean way would be a class, but meta-data may be preferred by standards):

```
$(".bar ." + fruits[i]).not(".bound").on('click', {...}).addClass('bound');
```

Comment: It sounds like a good solution.  But what happens when inventory is updated?  Will this just pass the initial data?  I tried this out just now and noticed it called the handler a number of times instead of once.  Then my browser crashed.